# Dropdownlist Cannot Remember Last Selected Value after returning to Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, html-select, selecteditem, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a custom Dropdownlist in my MVC4 application and although all the other Dropdownlist can remember the last selected value after returning to Razor View (i.e. due to not validating Model in Controller). How can I make this Dropdownlist to remember the selected value before submitting the form?

**View:** Code for using this Custom Dropdownlist

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Applicant.MeetingId)              
@Html.MyDropdownListFor(m => m.Applicant.MeetingId, ViewBag.MeetingData as List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>, 
null, new { name = "meetingId", id = "meetingId"})                   
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Applicant.MeetingId, null , new { @class = "ValidationErrors" })
```

**Controller:** Method for populating this Custom Dropdownlist

```
private void PopulateMeetingsDropDownList(object selectedMeetings = null)
{
    var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
        .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m, cA = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(z => z.cA.Select(cA => new { m = z.m, cA }))
        .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.m.ParticipantCityAId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m.m, m.cA, cB = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(w => w.cB.Select(cB => new { m = w.m, cA = w.cA, cB }))
        .GroupJoin(repository.Cities, m => m.m.ParticipantCityBId, c => c.CityID, (m, c) => new { m.m, m.cA, m.cB, cC = c.DefaultIfEmpty() })
        .SelectMany(t => t.cC.Select(cC => new { m = t.m, cA = t.cA, cB = t.cB, cC }))
        .Select(
            m =>
                new
                {
                    TotalParticipant = m.m.TotalParticipant,
                    MeetingID = m.m.MeetingID,
                    CityID = m.cA.CityID,
                    CityName = m.cA.CityName,
                    MeetingDate = m.m.MeetingStartDate,
                    MeetingName = m.m.MeetingName,
                    NameofMeetingCityIdA = m.cA != null ? m.cA.CityName : null,
                    NameofMeetingCityIdB = m.cB != null ? m.cB.CityName : null,
                    NameofMeetingCityIdC = m.cC != null ? m.cC.CityName : null
                })
        .OrderBy(x => x.CityName)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(
            i => new
            {
                Value = i.MeetingID.ToString(),
                DisplayValue = string.Format("{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})", i.NameofMeetingCityIdA, i.MeetingDate)),

                Expired = i.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow,
                MaksimumCount = i.TotalParticipant,
                CurrentCount = GetMeetingCount(i.MeetingID)
            }
        ).ToList();

    var selectItems = new List<MyHelpers.MySelectItem>(meetingsQuery.Count);
    foreach (var record in meetingsQuery)
    {
        var item = new MyHelpers.MySelectItem
        {
            Text = record.DisplayValue,
            Value = record.Value
        };
        //If Meeting Date is expired or Count for the current record >= Total Participant
        if (record.Expired || record.CurrentCount >= record.MaksimumCount)
        {
            item.Class = "disabled";
            item.Disabled = "disabled";
        }
        selectItems.Add(item);
    }
    ViewBag.MeetingData = selectItems;
}
```

**My Custom Helper:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyDropdownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<MySelectItem> list, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
        dropdown.Attributes.Add("name", name);
        dropdown.Attributes.Add("id", name);
        StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();

        // Make optionLabel the first item that gets rendered.
        if (optionLabel != null)
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + String.Empty + "'>" + optionLabel + "</option>");

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if(item.Disabled == "disabled")
                options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "' disabled='" + item.Disabled + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
            else
                options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Value + "' class='" + item.Class + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
        }
        dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
        dropdown.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Comment: By using VIEWDATA() you can get the last selected values from drop down

Comment: @PraveenS: Thanks for reply. Could you please an example by using the related code please? If it is possible to provide this by making changes on helper side, you might give your example on it. Regards...

Comment: Johnson Please search this on google there is an answer`Save dropdownlist state and Radio Button state after form submit in mvc 4 ASP.net`

Comment: @PraveenS: Actually I had looked at so much on the internet before asking the question and looked at with the help of your comment again. Unfortunately, there is not a solution suitable for my MVC4 application. Any idea?